# Problema con Printf y Scanf

Tags: c

Quiero hacer que mi programa pida ingresar una frase y luego una letra pero aunque la frase la pide bien la letra ya no la pide aunque SI muestra el texto "Letra: " que seguida de eso comienza la linea de comando de la consola...

El codigo es este:

```
char frase[100];
char letra;


printf("Frase: ");

scanf("%s", frase);

printf("Letra: ");

scanf("%c", &letra);
```

además, creo que si mi frase contiene mas de una palabra entonces no la considera...

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con

```
scanf("%s", frase);
```

En `frase` se almacenarán todos los caracteres que se escriban hasta que:

- Se lea todo el buffer
- Se encuentre un salto de linea
- Se encuentre un espacio en blanco

Por esta última condición, '%s' no es capaz de leer líneas completas. Para este cometido tienes `getline`:

```
int n;
char frase[100];

getline(frase,&n,stdin);
```

Aunque también puedes probar a programarlo por tu cuenta:

```
char* ptr = frase;
int c;
while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
{
  if( *ptr == '\n' )
  {
    *ptr = '\0';
    break;
  }
  *ptr = (char)c;
  ++ptr;
}

printf("\n%s",frase);
```

O, controlando que no se exceda de los 100 caracteres:

```
for( int i=0; i<99; i++ )
{
  int c = getchar();
  if( c == EOF || c == '\n' )
  {
    frase[i] = '\0';
    break;
  }
  frase[i] = (char)c;
}

frase[99] = '\0';

printf("\n%s",frase);
```

Comment: La pregunta no está marcada con la etiqueta C++, creo que sería prudente hacer cuanto menos una anotación al mencionar getline pues no va a funcionar en C plano.

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz [enlace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). Vale que C sea mas simplón que C++... pero no tanto

Comment: vaya, no sabía que glib tenia una implementación de getline. Aún así, sigo apoyando una anotación que diga que no es una función del estandar ISO.

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz [enlace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) te parece mejor si te paso el enlace a gnu? getline forma parte del estándar... otra cosa es que la función sea más o menos segura, pero ese es otro cantar

Comment: no dije que no fuera parte de ningún estándar, dije que no es parte del estándar ISO y de hecho en el mismo enlace que me has pasado en la segunda línea dice: "...So the GNU C Library provides the nonstandard getline function...". Nonstandard se refiere a que solo es parte de la implementación de GNU del lenguaje.

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz Cierto, ese detalle se me ha pasado.... sin que sirva de excusa soy mas de c++.. Aun así no veo necesario hacer tal comentario...  la respuesta ha sido aceptada y si a alguien no le funciona puede crear una nueva pregunta y ahí se responde con todo lujo de detalles el motivo y una solución.